# How to use sed command to change string in a file

Tags: windows, bash

OS: Windows 10

Tool: git bash

I want to use sed command to change the version string in some files.
In git bash, I tried below command and it works.

```
$ sed -i 's/1.0.0.21/1.0.0.22/g' ../fossa/PluginManifest.xml
```

Then I put sed command in a script file, like below:

```
$ cat UpdateVersion.sh
echo $1
echo $2
sed -i 's/$1/$2/g' ../fossa/PluginManifest.xml
```

And then I execute below command:

```
$ source UpdateVersion.sh 1.0.0.21 1.0.0.22
1.0.0.21
1.0.0.22
```

When I check the file, I find the version string is not changed. Why?

Comment: Use double quotes and escape the dots i.e. `"s/${1//./\\.}/$2/g"`

Comment: @anubhava Thank you very much! It works! Although I am not understand it. I will study it.

Comment: Single quotes won't let shell expand variables

Comment: a dot `.` in regex will be treated as "any character, except newline" if not escaped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, any and all input should validated, sanitized, and/or encoded as appropriate before use, especially for input being passed to a command/control interface, such as a shell-executed sed.

In your example, the following may be appropriate (with `.`s being escaped, as suggested by anubhava and mashuptwice, as unescaped `.`s instruct the regular expression engine to match *any* character):

```
  1 if [[ !( $1 =~ ^[0-9.]+$ && $2 =~ ^[0-9.]+$ ) ]]; then
  2     echo "Invalid version syntax" 1>&2
  3     exit 1
  4 fi
  5 
  6 ver1=${1//./\\.}
  7 ver2=${2//./\\.}
  8 
  9 sed -i "s/\b$ver1\b/$ver2/" ../fossa/PluginManifest.xml
```

Note that, `$ver1` is surrounded by `\b`s to ensure that `sed` matches on word boundaries (e.g., `sed s/1/a/g` would match on `1`, `(1)`, `12`, `21`, `121`, and `212` (replacing all `1`s with `a`), while `sed s/\b1\b/a/g` would only match on `1`, `(1)`, and other `1`s with word boundaries on both sides.

Consider reviewing the manpages for `bash` and `sed`, as well as the regular expressions tutorial here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/.